# "factor has new level" error during prediction using lm-model in SQL Server R Services

Tags: r, sql-server, linear-regression, lm

I am newbie in R, but trying to use it with SQL Server R Services.

As input to R script I select few numeric columns and one text column with categorical data. Let it be "company_name".

Then I execute:

```
 declare @script_r nvarchar(max) 
    = '
dat <- InputDataSet;
model <- lm(first_commission_received_delay ~ ., data = dat);
print(coef(model));
predict(model, dat);
'
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
        @language =N'R'
        , @script = @script_r 
        , @input_data_1 = @script_txt
```

But I am getting error:

> An external script error occurred:  Error in
>   model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev =
>   object$xlevels) :    factor company_name has new levels XXX
>   Calls: source ... predict -> predict.lm ->
>   model.frame -> model.frame.default

And in the list of coefficients which shown with function "print(coef(model))" there is no dummy variable "company_nameXXX", but exist all others.
I understand, that dummy variable "company_nameXXX" was not created because of multicollinearity.

But how to use calculated model for prediction? Even for the same set of data...
How to fix that error?

Answer (score 1):

I can fix that error using additional creation of dummy variables myself:

```
dat <- InputDataSet;

FactoredVariable = factor(dat$company_name) 
dumm = as.data.frame(model.matrix(~FactoredVariable)[,-1])
datWithDummies = cbind(dat[, -2], dumm) #join 2 tables except 2nd column (company_name) from dat #print(colnames(dat))

model <- lm(first_commission_received_delay ~ ., data = datWithDummies);
predicted.delay <- predict(model, datWithDummies);

print(cbind(predicted.delay, datWithDummies[, 1]))
```

But I still don't know, why my initial code returned error...

Comment: No one can help me to find solution?
Now I am trying another model (using glm function), but without additional creation of dummy variables myself always getting such "factor has new levels" errors. And it is only in the code executed from SQL Server.
Tried nearly the same steps locally in RStudio - there are no such errors. But I need to get results using SQL Server R Service